# static resource in angular and ionic application

Tags: angular

[image]

in my ionic project i have the hierarchy as in the image , i am trying to get products.json, but after starting the application i am trying to access the json file products.json , it says resources not available.

http://localhost:8100/pages/login/products.json

Comment: After your application build, the structure will be converted as JS bundles in flat structure. If these resource are static then the easiest way will be moving these .json files in side assets folder (as assets will be exposed as public after build generally. Other way is to configure some other folder as public and move all the json files to that folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your json file in **assets** folder

try code like below example :

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable()
export class HomePage {
private data: any;

 constructor(private http: Http) { }

 getData(){
   this.http.get('assets/data/products.json')
   .map((res) => res.json())
   .subscribe(data => {
      this.data = data;
   }, (rej) => {
          console.error("Could not load local data",rej)
   });
 }
}
```